# Applying an operation to groupings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

**EDIT**: I am not specifically looking into how to do this specific operation work, I need this sort of behaviour for a more complex function. So for the sake of the question, please pretend that the function takes a grouping and returns a data-frame that had some operation done on it (but no summation).

So say that I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "page": [
        1, 1, 1,
        2, 2, 2,
        3, 3, 3, 3
    ],
    "x": [
            10, 12, 21, 
            0, 5, 7, 
            1, 10, 33, 40
    ]
})
```

I want to compute the differences of each `x` within its respected page.

The way I devised it, is as such:

```
def compute_diff(group):
    return group.assign(
        diff = [
            *(group.x.values[1:] - group.x.values[0:len(group.x)-1]),
            None
        ]
    )

df.groupby('page').apply(compute_diff)
```

Now this works fine, but the problem is that I get a data-frame of data-frames, i.e. this:

```
        page    x   diff
page                
1   0   1   10  2.0
    1   1   12  9.0
    2   1   21  NaN
2   3   2   0   5.0
    4   2   5   2.0
    5   2   7   NaN
3   6   3   1   9.0
    7   3   10  23.0
    8   3   33  7.0
    9   3   40  NaN
```

Note, that my indexes are a bit messed up, how could I clean this up and get a format that looks more like this:

```
    page    x   diff                
0   1   10  2.0
1   1   12  9.0
2   1   21  NaN
3   2   0   5.0
4   2   5   2.0
5   2   7   NaN
6   3   1   9.0
7   3   10  23.0
8   3   33  7.0
9   3   40  NaN
```

I have tried a few things with unstack and reset_index, but the results are not quite what I want, and there isn't anything I noticed in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `GroupBy.diff` instead?

```
df.assign(diff=df.groupby('page').x.diff())

   page   x  diff
0     1  10   NaN
1     1  12   2.0
2     1  21   9.0
3     2   0   NaN
4     2   5   5.0
5     2   7   2.0
6     3   1   NaN
7     3  10   9.0
8     3  33  23.0
9     3  40   7.0
```

---

If you insist on using `apply`, also use `group_keys=False`:

```
df.groupby('page', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(compute_diff)

   page   x  diff
0     1  10   2.0
1     1  12   9.0
2     1  21   NaN
3     2   0   5.0
4     2   5   2.0
5     2   7   NaN
6     3   1   9.0
7     3  10  23.0
8     3  33   7.0
9     3  40   NaN
```

Comment: I used that operation as an example. My actual code has something slightly more complex. I was hoping to get a solution that is "operation" indifferent.

Comment: @asosnovsky Is this better now?

Answer (score 1):

Using `.iloc` with `diff`

```
df['diff']=df.groupby('page').x.apply(lambda x : -x.iloc[::-1].diff()).sort_index(level=0).values
df
Out[106]: 
   page   x  diff
0     1  10   2.0
1     1  12   9.0
2     1  21   NaN
3     2   0   5.0
4     2   5   2.0
5     2   7   NaN
6     3   1   9.0
7     3  10  23.0
8     3  33   7.0
9     3  40   NaN
```